# Join base url to relative url in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Im new to python and scrapy. Im having trouble joining the base url to the srapped link.
Iv tried a number of suggestions but probably executing it incorrectly

```
def parse(self, response):
    for ad_links in response.xpath('//div[@class="view"][1]//a'):
        yield {
            'title': item.xpath('text()').extract(),
            relative_url = item.xpath('@href').extract(),
            'link': response.urljoin(relative_url),
            }
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instanciate a variable inside the dictionary you are yielding, it makes no sense.

And be sure to understand the difference between extract() and extract_first(), I have the feeling that extract_first is the method to use here. See [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=extract_first#extracting-data).

What is this item variable ? Should be ad_links right ?

Try this :

```
def parse(self, response):
    for ad_links in response.xpath('//div[@class="view"][1]//a'):
        relative_url = ad_links.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        yield {
            'title': ad_links.xpath('text()').extract_first(),
            'link': response.urljoin(relative_url),
            }
```

Comment: It worked & makes perfect sense, thanks very much Corentin!